# Expose web server running on Android on Verizon 3G to the internet?

Tags: android

It is possible to serve web pages from a android phone over 3G network to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your network provider.  Most of them place phones into walled garden behind NAT - so it is not possible to reach them from outside.

Comment: How would I find out whether Verizon allows this?

Comment: check configured IP address via "adb shell netcfg"   my 3g device is called rmnet0 and  has IP address: 10.56.73.104 which is clearly in private IP address range - also, this is NATed garden and not outside connection possible

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible provided you are able to run a decent web server and the port 80 is available?

But I am curious why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I don't mean over wifi on my local network, I mean over Verizon's 3G network. Want to know if they block incoming port 80 IPv6 requests, etc.

Comment: Why do such a thing? So that I can remote control my phone from another computer.

Comment: not if your provider uses private IP address range - and most probably he does